# What is a "PowerShell prompt"?

Tags: powershell

I would like to delete many of the automatically included apps from my Windows 10 laptop.  I do not know what a powershell prompt is, or how to get to it.

Comment: The PowerShell prompt is a command-line interface. In this you can run PowerShell commands. Further information [here](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/simple-questions-what-powershell-what-can-you-do-it). You should be able to turn this off through Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows Features On or Off.

Comment: I suspect they want to find PowerShell so that they can run some commands to remove some Windows features, not so they can remove powershell itself.

Comment: deleting any files in the System32 folder is a bad idea. Many apps may use cmd and powershell internally to do their jobs

Comment: Is it really faster to register account here, type a question then wait till some1 reply instead of to place the same question on google?

Comment: @Alex - Sometimes, Google can't answer the question adequately. Sometimes, asking the question in the 'natural' way doesn't get interpreted properly. I certainly go to "Bingleduck" (Bing, Google, DuckDuckGo) _first_, but when I want solid, well-researched, complete answers, I'll come to StackExchange.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I mostly agree with you, but if you copy/paste this particular question `what is a powershell prompt` in google(exact question OP asked), at least first page from search result giving "solid, well-researched, complete answers", so I just was curious(no sarcastic), if that effort to create account and asking it here is really deserve spent time.

Answer (score 0):

The PowerShell prompt is similar to the Windows Command Prompt (aka DOS prompt) but runs a different, more powerful, interpreter which provides object level access to more parts of the operating system. To get to it open your start menu and just start typing the word "powershell." You should see an application listed "Windows PowerShell" click on it to launch a PowerShell prompt. Right click on it and choose run as administrator if you need one with administrative permissions.

Answer (score -1):

It's a better, more powerful version of the old DOS command prompt. You can manually run it from the Start menu.  It's used/useful for many system configurations/applications.  I wouldn't delete it unless you're absolutely certain you'll never do anything more than say word processing on that laptop..  And even then you might be messing up some important upgrades.  In a word:  no :-).